# Non-optional expression of type 'AnyObject' used in a check for optionals

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, anyobject

I created an extension on 'Dictionary' to help me parse JSON. The method below helps me do this:

```
func toJSONString() -> String? {
    if let dict = self as? AnyObject {
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
            if let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                return json
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The issue occurs on this line:

```
if let dict = self as? AnyObject {
```

I get a warning saying "Non-optional expression of type 'AnyObject' used in a check for optionals"

How do I go about solving this issue?

Comment: You don't need to unwrap or cast `self`, you already know it's a dictionary.  Just pass `self` directly to the `JSONSerialization.data(...)` function.

Comment: The error message says: The object is not an optional, `if let` can not be used.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you answer your own question please, interested to see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the line that causes warning from your code and pass `self` as is for the `JSONSerialization` function. This should work without any issues:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func toJSONString() -> String? {
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
            if let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                return json
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are unwrapping something that was already unwrapped. Take a look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884167/swift-3-warning-non-optional-expression-of-type-string-used-in-a-check-for-op)