# Non-optional expression of type 'String' used in a check for optionals

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting this warning from Xcode Swift 5, here is my code I don't get what is wrong, I use this to remove any new line or tab at the end of my String (line)

My code:

`let url: String = String(line.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })`

**UPDATE**

I was doing it inside an **if let** and was using the type cast operator here is the solution and the rest of code and an example of the line value.

```
let line = " http://test.com/testing.php \n"
if let url: String = line.filter({!" \n\t\r".contains($0)}) as String?
{
       //More action here
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you enter that code in a playground by itself (with some definition of `line`) do you still get the error?

Comment: What is `line`? A self-contained [mcve] and the exact error message would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 3 warning: Non-optional expression of type 'String' used in a check for optionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884167/swift-3-warning-non-optional-expression-of-type-string-used-in-a-check-for-op)

Comment: The correct solution would be to remove the (unnecessary) optional binding, not to add an artificial  cast `as String?`.

Answer (score 0):

to me this line looks good, but you may be missing the parentheses for the string filter method. Here's two ways I did it in playground. Let me know if this works for you, or how I can help further.

```
var line = "\t Hello, line removal \n \t Another new line \n"

let filteredClosure = line.filter { (char) -> Bool in
    return !"\n\t\r".contains(char)
}

let filterShorthand = line.filter({!"\n\t\r".contains($0)})
```

With the line you provided, I would expect white-space to be removed too. If that's what you're looking for, add a space inside the filter string: ***" \n\t\r"***

Comment: I just see why I'm getting the warning it's because I was doing it inside an `if let`

Comment: ahh good, let me know if anything else seems strange. I'm here to help